# MySQL Select columns which has two matches in other table

Tags: mysql

I am sorry if this question was already solved, but I did not know how to word my problem properly or what I should search for.

So I have 2 tables:

**groups**

```
id | name
```

**memberships**

```
id | user_id | group_id
```

What I am trying to do is find all groups which the user with id 1 is a member of and also user with id 2 is a member of.
Obviously that does not work:

```
SELECT groups.id FROM groups, memberships WHERE groups.id = memberships.group_id AND memberships.user_id = 1 AND memberships.user_id = 2;
```

I hope you understand my issue, I am having trouble finding the right words for the problem. Feel free to ask.

Edit: Both users should be a member of the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, you need groups where both users are members?

Something like:

```
SELECT g1.id 
FROM groups g1, memberships m1, groups g2, memberships m2
WHERE m1.group_id = g1.id AND m1.user_id = 1
AND m2.group_id = g2.id AND m2.user_id = 2
AND g1.group_id = g2.group_id;
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Seems to do exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your last `AND` with `OR` and put the test of the `user_id` into `(`, like this :

```
SELECT groups.id 
FROM groups, memberships 
WHERE groups.id = memberships.group_id 
AND (memberships.user_id = 1 OR memberships.user_id = 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   groups g 
       INNER JOIN memberships m 
               ON m.group_id = g.id 
WHERE  m.user_id = '1' 
        OR m.user_id = '2'
```

Comment: It also returns groups which either one of the two users is a member of. Milan Zavišić posted a working query.

Comment: @Adura, Well I thought that was what you wanted?